# Incorrect byte[] value when html tag is used

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an html helper method for a hidden field. It is bound to a byte[] and I have no problem as it displays the result correctly. But instead of the helper function if I use an html tag, the correct value is not displayed. Instead it displays its type.

following code and image will clarify what I am trying to say.

HTML code:

```
foreach (var path in Model.PathToImages)
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-sm-6" style="vertical-align:central;">
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary delete-property" name="@path.ImagePath" />
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => path.ConcurrencyCheck)
            <input id="@path.ImagePath" name="@path.ImagePath" type="hidden" value="@path.ConcurrencyCheck">
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Property in my model:

```
public byte[] ConcurrencyCheck { get; set; }
```

Ignoring the names and id's of the control (this is just to reproduce the problem), following is the html generated:

[image]

Now as the image says when i use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => path.ConcurrencyCheck)` the value is correctly displayed but when I use `<input id="@path.ImagePath" name="@path.ImagePath" type="hidden" value="@path.ConcurrencyCheck">` the value is the type System.Byte[].

So why I am not getting the value when I am using the html input tag or the problem is with the way model value should be displayed.

Comment: have tried converting the ConcurrencyCheck value to string? It seems like the browser can't interpret do it implicitly and just writing the type of it whereas when you use the mvc engine to resolve it for you, it implicitly converts the value

Comment: yes that has given me the same result

Comment: how did you attempt to convert it? because in your model.pathToImages loop the type is var. and @path.ConcurrencyCheck is in the html so it is not resolved by the engine. maybe if you model property getter returned a string value instead of just the default get, it could work.

Comment: only other thing you use from the model in the loop is the ImagePath which I am assuming is a string path so that works on its own as the text is fine in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because `byte[]` is a a complex array and needs to be converted to `Base64String`. The `Html.HiddenFor()` method takes this into account but `@path.ConcurrencyCheck` does not, and is using the `.ToString()` method of the properties value to generate the output.

You can view the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs), but the relevant lines of code are

```
private static MvcHtmlString HiddenHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ModelMetadata metadata, object value, bool useViewData, string expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
    ....
    byte[] byteArrayValue = value as byte[];
    if (byteArrayValue != null)
    {
        value = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArrayValue);
    }
    ....
```